# How to prevent WebSphere from starting before files from an application update have been unpacked

Tags: performance, websphere, web-deployment

Using the WebSphere Integrated Solutions Console, a large (18,400 file) web application is updated by specifying a war file name and going through the update screens and finally saving the configuration.  The Solutions Console web UI spins a while, then it returns, at which point the user is able to start the web application.

**If the application is started after the "successful update", it fails because the files that are the web application have not been exploded out to the deployment directory yet.**

Experimentation indicates that it takes on the order of **12 minutes for the files to appear!**

One more bit of background that may be significant: There are 19 application servers on this one WebSphere instance. WebSphere insists that there be a lot of chatter between them, even though they don't need anything from each other. I wondered if this might be slowing things down when it comes to deployment.  Or if there's some timer in the bowels of WebSphere that is just set wrong (usual disclaimers apply...I'm just showing up and finding this situation...I didn't configure this installation).

Additional Information:
This is a **Network Deployment configuration**, and it's all on one physical host.
* ND 6.1.0.23

Comment: Dale, The chatter is probably the HA Manager in action. It is an underlying component in WAS to provide High Availability services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a standalone or a ND set up? I am guessing it is ND set up considering you have stated that they are 19 app servers. The nodes should be synchronized with the deployment manager so that the updated files are available to the respective nodes.

After you update and save the changes, try and synchronize the nodes with the dmgr (or alternatively as part of the update process, click on review and the check the box which says synchronize nodes) and this would distribute the changes to the various nodes.

The default interval, i believe is 1 minute.

12 minutes certainly sounds a lot. Is there any possibility of network being an issue here?

HTH

Manglu

Comment: Manglu, Thanks for your comment.  Updated the question (yes ND, one physical host).  Update > review > synchronize nodes checkbox did not seem to change anything (still long delay).

Comment: Dale, How many nodes do you have? Can we try something here? Check what happens if you use a small EAR file and see how long it takes vs one which is 18400 files. The internals use HTTP to transfer the files from the deployment manager to the node agents. I am guessing it is taking a long time for this HTTP upload. We can see if that is the case by trying out a few file sizes. How big is the Web Application in MB? I  don't know of any specialized tuning knob to improve HTTP Upload for this file synchronization process.

Comment: Thanks again Manglu for the thoughtful ideas. Size is 96MB. I have handed this off to a support guy now, but I should be able to find some time in the next couple of weeks to experiment. I'll let you know.